# Windows 10: Remove Read-only Attribute from a "Folder" via PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, read-only

I am trying this line of code but it doesn't seem to effect folders, just files?

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Recurse -File | % { $_.IsReadOnly=$false }
```

Ok, so I removed the -File from the command and I am getting this error:

> The property 'IsReadOnly' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.

However, if I right click on the folder > Properties, it clearly shows Read-only checked.

Comment: I am using Windows 10

Comment: Folders don't have a read-only attribute. This can be seen if you open the property page of a folder that has the addition (only applies to folders in the directory). Also note that the check-box is neither checked nor clear, it is just filled which means "undefined".

Comment: The user has full access to these folders yet they are unable to delete, I can delete them as a domain admin but they can't. Its weird... The only odd thing I see is the Read-only button checked. I was hoping to run a script to remove the read-only on all of them. I guess this isn't my issue then

Comment: Are you sure the ACL entries of the files are correct? And the user did not deleted himself from the allowed users?

Comment: @Robert: They do, [despite what the GUI shows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/326549/you-cannot-view-or-change-the-read-only-or-the-system-attributes-of-fo). The attribute bitmask is still arranged the same for both files and folders, and it can be set and cleared, it just doesn't _make_ the folder read-only at all (so Windows Explorer uses it for [a different purpose](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20030930-00/?p=42353)).

Comment: It not quite correct it does nothing. The old documentation says you cannot delete a read only folder. Explorer ignored the rules but the command prompt doesn't. You cannot delete a read only folder at the command prompt, still. Here's a small program that lists all 19 attributes of a file/folder/volume https://winsourcecode.blogspot.com/2019/05/listattrexe-lists-all-19-of-attributes.html

Answer (score 2):

Don't look at the folder's **Properties** dialog, *the **Read-only** checkbox is not a status indicator*! To see if a folder's Read-only attribute is set, add the **Attributes** column to a **Details** view of the parent folder.

To set/clear a folder's Read-only attribute in **POerShell**, use:

```
$Folder = Get-Item 'C:\Path\to\folder' # or any other vald way to obtain a IO.DirectoryInfo object
$Folder.Attributes -= 'ReadOnly' # clear REad-only
$Folder.Attributes += 'ReadOnly' # set REad-only
```

Note that clearing the attibute prevents processing of a folder's **desktop.ini** file, so custom icons, etc. are not applied.